# Stabilizing Wi-Fi ping

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, latency

I've been having some issues with in-game lag spikes.  Nothing game breaking, but they can be troublesome.  I have two routers: one from Xfinity that comes straight from the ISP, and one linked to the router/modem box by Linksys: WRT 1900.

I've done some reconfiguration, with some possible improvement, and some other strange behavior has popped up.

Using my computer and phone as pinging devices.

- Linksys router default gateway: 192.168.1.1
- Xfinity router default gateway: 10.0.0.1

When pinging either with my computer, I would get pings in the 200-400ms range, but it would read:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 64 bytes of information 
Reply from 1.1.168.192 ... 231ms
```

It also had stopped being able to ping 192.168.1.1 with an error of "request timed out".

And if I reverse the ping location to 1.1.168.192,

```
Pinging 1.1.168.192
Reply from 192.168.1.1 ... 5ms
```

it pings in the 1-7ms range

My phone pings 192.168.1.1 in the 1-7ms range
and 1.1.168.192 in the 200-400ms range – i.e., *the reverse* of the computer.

10.0.0.1 has the same basic story except:

- My computer can only ping 1.0.0.10, again getting a response from 10.0.0.1
- My phone can only ping 10.0.0.1

Both averaging 7ms.

---

I'm connected over Wi-Fi.  My wireless card is ASUS PCE-AC56 AC1300.
The router I'm connected to corresponds to the address I'm pinging.
Both are broadcasting a Wi-Fi signal.

I pinged the inverse because when I pinged 192.168.1.1 it read

```
Reply from 1.1.168.192
```

and thought it would work some kind of magic.  Apparently it 'worked', but if 1.x.x.x is reserved for Asia: that makes it even stranger that I got a better ping from it.

The Xfinity router is plugged into the Linksys router as well as a Vonage phone line.  The Linksys router was plugged into the phone line, which I swapped to the Xfinity router/modem.  I think it helped some.

Both have DHCP enabled on IPV4 and IPV6
They both have 5 devices connected, but none are active except for the computer/phone that I am using.

What other information is needed to troubleshoot this?  I'm really at a brick wall.

---

Here is a transcript from cmd using command:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 >Pings.txt
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.168.192: bytes=32 time=267ms TTL=44
Request timed out.
Reply from 1.1.168.192: bytes=32 time=269ms TTL=44
Reply from 1.1.168.192: bytes=32 time=295ms TTL=44

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 267ms, Maximum = 295ms, Average = 277ms
```

I'm running Windows 10 Pro.

Also, here's me running the inverse IP:

```
Pinging 1.1.168.192 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 1.1.168.192:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: WUT? Why are you pinging the inverse? 1.x.x.x is a reserved block for Asia I think. Note that there was a UI bug where disabling inbound ping on the xfinity router prevented all outbound pings. You should be more clear on the layout here, WAN/LAN ports plugged, how you are connected when pinging; if both routers have dhcp enabled; which wireless receiver you are connecting to. etc.etc

Comment: Dan Kadlec: Welcome to Super User.  Are you and [Ninjas Kill](//superuser.com/users/684646/ninjas-kill) the same person?  If so, it would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/684623/dan-kadlec and https://superuser.com/users/684646/ninjas-kill.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: You claim that you are doing `ping 192.168.1.1` and getting `Reply from 1.1.168.192`. This is unheard of. Can you copy the command and its complete output from your command window into your question? And what OS are you running?

Comment: Thank you G-Man, I have merged my accounts.

I have also provided the copy of the output from pinging 192.168.1.1

Comment: According to the popular MaxMind Geo IP location service, the IP address 1.1.168.192 is likely in Chiang Mai, Thailand. OP, if you're in North America, it makes sense that your ping time would be around 277ms. Now, how your ping client or your router is mixing up 192.168.1.1 and 1.1.168.192 is one of the strangest things I've seen on SuperUser.

Comment: Is there any chance you've got `in-addr.arpa` in your list of DNS search domains, on your Win 10 client or either of your routers?

Comment: How would I check that?  I figure since the rDNS doesn't happen with my phone, it would probably be on the client side of my computer.